# Qt event data destructor

Tags: qt, qt-signals

Suppose there is a qt-object with signal. This object emits a signal which contains some object allocated on the heap (new/malloc). Event's destructor releases all allocated data. Will such data be released in any way if there is no connection to qt-object signal? If a listener closes connection before an event receiving in it's signal slot?

ADDITIONS:

Example with shortens.

```
  class MyEvent { virtual ~MyEvent(); }; // root class for all my project events
  class MyEventQueue {
      MyEventQueue();                // initialize mutex
      virtual ~MyEventQueue();       // delete and release all events from events_
      void push_back( MyEvent *);    // atomic-push event
      MyEvent *pop_front();          // atomic-pop  event
      pthread_mutex_t sync_;         // mutex for atomic operations
      std::queue<MyEvent *> events_; // queue of events
  };
  class MyEvent1 : public MyEvent {
      MyEvent1( char *);
      ~MyEvent1() { delete[] data; }
      char *data;
  };
  class MyWriter {
      ...;
      void eval();
      signals: void send1( MyEventQueue *);
      MyEventQueue queue_;
  };
  class MyReader {
      ...;
      slots: void recv1( MyEventQueue *);
  };
  class MyController {
      ...;
  }
```

MyWriter and MyReader are independet actors working in different threads of one process.

```
void MyWriter::eval() {
    ...;
    queue_.push_back( new MyEvent1( ...));
    emit send1( &queue_);
}

void MyReader::recv1( MyEventQueue *queue) {
    if ( MyEvent *event = queue->pop_front() ) {
        // event is delivered to MyReader
        ...;
        delete event;
    }
}
```

If a sended event was delivered and accepted it will be deleted in MyReader. In other way event will be kept in MyWriter::queue_.

MyController works as a dispatcher/manager for MyWriter and MyReader. Also it realizes communications with other functional blocks. At the end of the (extern) data processing cycle MyController stops MyWriter, MyReader (their threads and so on their qt-event loops). Then it closes a connection beetwen MyWriter and MyReader. If some events was sended by MyWriter, but not accepted by MyReader then allocated datas will be released in ~MyWriter() -> queue_'s destructor.

(For multiply readers I use an explicit resending in MyController with events coping or only one to one connections, in this case MyController works as a router with self event-queues.)

The main reason is pipelining and parallelization of data processing.

I doubt that possibly I duplicate qt-engine work. Of course, there may be a better solution at all.

Comment: As you stated yourself, `MyEvent` objects will be destructed in `~MyEventQueue` or in `MyReader::recv1`. This seems to be fine (if correctly implemented, also `~MyEventQueue` should probably use the mutex). So what is your question?

Comment: Note that it may be useful to let `MyReader::recv1` process all pending events, as the signal may be emitted before the slot was connected, resulting in some events never being processed.

Comment: If you do not need the queueing behaviour of `MyEventQueue`, i.e. if the signal-slot connection is made before events are generated, you could simply pass the MyEvent object. In that case a shared pointer may be useful to enforce destruction.

Comment: And alternative to using signal and slots in this case may be to use [`QWaitCondition`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwaitcondition.html) to signal the availability of new data.

Comment: At first MyController connects signal and slot and only after that starts MyWriter and MyReader. When I started to use qt-signals I met many surprises and it was difficult to me to understand qt-signals and make working programm. I still don't sure enough about full correctness of my using qt-signals. In other hand I think that same tasks must be decided numerous times. So I want to uderstand was solution with queues reasonable or/and to know better solution. What about QWaitCondition and shared pointers - I will take to look.

Comment: I think `QWaitCondition` is the most efficient way for your use case, i.e. pipelined data processing

Comment: A Qt approach is to pass by value/reference and employ a copy-on-write approach to make it efficient (f.ex. used by `QString`): see [Implicit sharing](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/implicit-sharing.html) for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**General recommendations about passed arguments to signal**

It's up to you to destruct an objects passed as an argument of a signal. Note that multiple slots may be connected to the same signal, which may result in destructing the object multiple times.

Some (common) possibilities are:

- Pass by const reference. Qt will create a copy when a [queued connection](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum) is used. Otherwise, no copy will be made.
- Pass by value. Useful for basic types, otherwise pass by const reference.
- Pass a shared pointer.

Another option may be to check whether a slot is connected to the signal, using [`QObject::isSignalConnected`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#isSignalConnected). This function is especially useful to avoid the emission of the signal in case the arguments are resource intensive to construct. However, I do not recommend this option for your case, as it doesn't solve the case when multiple slots are connected to the same signal.

Another possibility is to implement your own callback method, which would allow you to enforce a unique callback method.